# How can I confirm if a thread was previously attached via AttachThreadInput?

Tags: c++, winapi

**tl;dr**

When using the `AttachThreadInput` function I can choose to either attach or detach another thread.

Is there a way of knowing if an attachment already exists?

**long version**

I have class A:

```
ClassA::attach(::HWND window)
{ 
    ::AttachThreadInput(::GetCurrentThreadId(), ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, NULL), TRUE);
}

ClassA::detach(::HWND window)
{ 
    ::AttachThreadInput(::GetCurrentThreadId(), ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, NULL), FALSE);
}

ClassA::doSomething()
{
    // things happen
}
```

...and class B:

```
ClassB::doSomethingElse(::HWND window)
{
    ::AttachThreadInput(::GetCurrentThreadId(), ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, NULL), TRUE);

    // do something else

    ::AttachThreadInput(::GetCurrentThreadId(), ::GetWindowThreadProcessId(window, NULL), FALSE);
}
```

I want to amend class B so that it is aware of already existing attachments, and only attach/detach if an attachment doesn't already exist.

This will allow me to do something like this:

```
ClassA a;
ClassB b;

a.attach(window);
b.doSomethingElse(window);
a.doSomething();
a.detach(window);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API to query for an existing attachment.  You have to keep track of the attachments yourself.